# difference between the linear predictor with uncertainty and predictive distribution for a new observation

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, inference

I was reading an extract from the book  "regression and other stories" and at chapter 9 the author distinguish between 3 cases

"After fitting a regression, $y = a + bx + error$, we can use it to predict a new data point, or a set of
new data points, with predictors $x_{new}$. We can make three sorts of predictions, corresponding to increasing levels of uncertainty:

1. The point prediction,$\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_{new}$: Based on the fitted model, this is the best point estimate of the average value of y for new data points with this new value of x. We use $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ here because the point prediction ignores uncertainty.
2. The linear predictor with uncertainty, $a + bx_{new}$, propagating the inferential uncertainty in $(a, b)$: This represents the distribution of uncertainty about the expected or average value of y for new data points with predictors $x_{new}$
3. The predictive distribution for a new observation, $a + bx_{new} + error$: This represents uncertainty about a new observation y with predictors $x_{new}$.

and then it makes the example

" For example, consider a study in which blood pressure, $y$, is predicted from the dose, $x$, of a drug.
For any given $x_{new}$, the point prediction is the best estimate of the average blood pressure in the
population, conditional on dose $x_{new}$; the linear predictor is the modeled average blood pressure of
people with dose $x_{new}$ in the population, with uncertainty corresponding to inferential uncertainty
in the coefficients $a$ and $b$; and the predictive distribution represents the blood pressure of a single
person drawn at random drawn from this population, under the model conditional on the specified
value of $x_{new}$.
As sample size approaches infinity, the coefficients a and b are estimated more and more precisely,
and the uncertainty in the linear predictor approaches zero, but the uncertainty in the predictive
distribution for a new observation does not approach zero; it approaches the residual standard
deviation $σ$"

but honestly  i am not sure i understood the difference between 2) and 3)

suppose i have a model $y= f(x,a,b,c)$ that depends on a predictor variable $x$ and 3 other coefficients $a,b,c$ and i sample the posterior distribution with EMCEE or another software and find the best fit coefficients $\hat a, \hat b, \hat c$.

if :

1. i substitute the value of $a,b,c$ with the best fit coefficients at a point $x_{new}$ i get the point prediction

case 2 should correspond to finding the uncertainty on the model expected value of $y_{pred}$ at $x_{new}$ and should correspond to this procedure (i think):

1. fix $x= x_{new}$ and
2. take the samples of $a,b,c$ and
3. collect  all the $f(x_{new},a,b,c)$
4. compute the mean and the variance  to get the distribution of uncertainty about the
   model average value of y

but what's case 3 and what is the procedure ? and what does it mean "  under the model conditional on the specified value of $x_{new}$"
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty might be that $y = f(x, a, b, c)$ is too abstract of a notation and doesn't fully specify a particular model.

So let's take simple linear regression as an example: $y = a + bx + e$ with $e \sim \operatorname{N}(0, c)$. In this model $a$ is the intercept, $b$ is the slope and $c$ is the error variance.

- Goal #2 (linear prediction with uncertainty) is to estimate $\operatorname{E}(y_{new} | x_{new}) = a + bx_{new}$.
- Goal #3 (predictive distribution for a new observation) is to predict $y_{new} | x_{new} \sim N(a + bx_{new}, c)$.

Let's also assume that you've already fitted the model, so you have a sample $\big\{\widehat{a}^{(k)}, \widehat{b}^{(k)}, c^{(k)}\big\}$ from the posterior $(a,b,c) | x$ given a dataset $x$; $k$ indexes the posterior draws.

To estimate $\operatorname{E}(y_{new} | x_{new})$, you proceed as you describe: you calculate $\big\{ \widehat{a}^{(k)} + \widehat{b}^{(k)}x_{new} \big\}$ for each posterior draw. (No need for $\widehat{c}$ here.) This is a sample from the posterior distribution of $\operatorname{E}(y_{new} | x_{new})$ and you can get an estimate of its mean & variance, plot its histogram, etc.

To predict $y_{new} | x_{new}$, you additionally draw an error $e^{(k)}$ for each posterior draw $k$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{(k)} &\sim \operatorname{N}\big(0, \widehat{c}^{(k)}\big) \\
y^{(k)} &= \widehat{a}^{(k)} + \widehat{b}^{(k)}x_{new} + e^{(k)}
\end{aligned}
$$

So "under the model conditional on the specified value of $x_{new}$" means that you know how to sample from the model $f(a,b,c)$ given a specific value for the predictor $x_{new}$ and a set of parameter values $\big(\widehat{a}, \widehat{b}, \widehat{c}\big)$. For simple linear regression, this means drawing an error $e$ from a normal distribution and adding it to the estimate of $\operatorname{E}(y_{new} | x_{new})$.

Clearly, there is more uncertainty in predicting a new observation $y_{new} | x_{new}$ than the population mean $\operatorname{E}(y_{new} | x_{new})$ due to the additional variability of drawing the (individual) error $e$.

And here is how to do add this extra variability in R code (pp. 116 in *Regression and Other Stories*):

```r
y_pred <- a + b * as.numeric(new) + rnorm(n_sims, 0, c)
```

where I've substituted `sigma` with `c` for consistency.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. can i ask one thing? shouldn't the error term be estimated like the others without assuming any distribution? after all the model may be not perfect at all ranges.  i added a term e with flat priors  in a interval [-5,5] centered around 0.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "like the others without assuming any distribution". Isn't a flat prior on the interval [-5,5], the same as saying Uniform(-5, 5)? And, choosing a very vague prior because the model might not be perfect, isn't necessarily a good approach.

Comment: Perhaps you mix up "flat prior" with "no distribution"? In Bayesian analysis everything has a distribution (the parameters and the data). And again flat priors are often a poor choice.

Comment: ah yes i meant Uniform distribution. Is it better to switch to normal?

Comment: Yes, I think so. If your errors are Uniform(-5, 5) instead of centered at 0, doesn't this mean that your measurement instrument is very inaccurate?

Comment: but my model can, for example, systematically under predict the  values... in that case the error would not be centered around zero

Comment: Two comments: (1) The followup question doesn't have much in common with the question in this thread. If you would like to ask for feedback about this, then you should consider writing a new question. You would need to include all relevant background about the problem you are working on. (2) It's not clear whether your model indeed undepredicts (you have evidence for this?) or you think you can guard against this possibility with a uniform error model. I don't know any details, but uniform error model sounds like a bad choice to me.

Comment: ok, sorry, one last question  on topic then:   the procedure to find  `E(ynew|xnew)`, can i say that i am marginalizing over the parameters of the model? in general, is there a specific term that is used to describe this procedure?

Comment: $\operatorname{E}(y_{new}|x_{new})$ is the posterior mean of a new observation with $x_{new}$. Now that you fitted your Bayesian model, you can estimate the posterior distribution of all kinds of quantities and $\operatorname{E}(y_{new}|x_{new})$ is one particular example. I would describe it this way.

Comment: @dipetkow hi, does this procedure to propagate the error works even if i use a  functions of the parameters a and b that is different from the model that i used to fit the posterior?

Comment: No. Bayesian analysis assumes that you've specified a full model that has a precise form. If you change any part of the model, then you have to refit it.

Comment: mmm i am not sure if what i meant was clear. let me rephrase just to be sure: suppose that i have used my model m1 to model the distance and find the parameters  a and b, and then i want to compute the value of the energy E= E(a,b) , can i still use the posterior samples collected  with m1 to propagate the error on E?

Comment: I apologize but the Q&A format means that comments are not the right place to ask follow-up questions. I genuinely don't see what this new question has to do with the section of Regression and Other Stories quoted in the original question. Consider writing a new question instead.